# How to save a file to a specific spot on the phone

Tags: java, android

I would like for my app to create a folder on the sd card and save a file in it. This is what I have right now that just saves it in my app data.

```
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(""), fileName);         

    FileOutputStream os = null; 

    try { 
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(os);
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
        success = true; 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
    } finally { 
        try { 
            if (null != os) 
                os.close(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
        } 
    }
```

How would I do that?

Alright so I did this. Am I even doing this right?

```
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "";
    File file = new File(fullPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }


    FileOutputStream os = null; 

    try { 
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(os);
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
        success = true; 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
    } finally { 
        try { 
            if (null != os) 
                os.close(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: It's simpler than that, see my update to answer your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to find the root path to use.

However, please note that this is not nessasarily the sd-card, from the [docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Example, just change your first line to be:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
```

Need a directory?:

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourdir");
 dir.mkDirs();
 File file = new File(dir, fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Create file folder like this

```
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Foldername";
File dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
```